# Team Foundation Server 2015 git repo with submodules on external git servers

Tags: git, tfs, git-submodules, tfs-2015

I've got Team Foundation Server 2015 installed. Everything is working great expect one thing.

I am working with two main [git](/questions/tagged/git) repositories (Created from team projects). The build for the first repository works great but the build for the second repository has problems.

The first has sub-modules that live on the TFS [git](/questions/tagged/git) server itself. The build works great here.

The second has sub-modules that live on a different [git](/questions/tagged/git) server. When this build runs TFS fails to obtain those submodules:

```
******************************************************************************
    Starting: Get sources
******************************************************************************
Syncing repository: my_app (Git)
Checking out dbab6... to C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-UTP120W-1\_work\5\s with submodules

Object not found - no matching loose object (f8334...)

Prepare repository failed with exception.
```

(I've abbreviated the SHA's here for simplicity)

The SHA that starts with `f8334...` is the submodule that lives on an external git server. My guess is that this error:

> Object not found - no matching loose object

actually has something to do with the credentials that TFS is attempting to use on the remote server. Is there a way to see which credentials TFS is using to interact with the remote server? Is there a way to configure these credentials myself?

I attempted to change the `repository type` in the build settings from `git` to `external git` so that I could specify credentials. However, this results in yet a different error:

```
******************************************************************************
    Starting: Get sources
******************************************************************************
Syncing repository: my_app (Git)

Too many redirects or authentication replays

Prepare repository failed with exception.
```

Google results for both this error:

> Too many redirects or authentication replays

and the previous don't seem to turn up anything useful for this scenario. Anyone have any clues?

**UPDATE**

It looks like TFS 2015 only supports repos with [submodules that are in TFS itself, or are anonymously accessible](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3606383-add-submodule-support-in-visual-studio-git-extensi). However, a [new feature request was created](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519/suggestions/11462817) to address external authentication for submodules.

However, in my case the external git server *is anonymously accessible*. So, unfortunately, I'm guessing that the problem somehow lies with my external git server? For reference it is the open source software [Bonobo Git server](https://bonobogitserver.com/).

Comment: How do you add a sub-module to a Git repository? Can you add the sub-module that live on an external git server to your second git repository with command "git submodule add [URL to Git repo]" ?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I can and have added them just as you mention ie: `git submodule add git@mygithost:billboard lib/billboard` and yes I can add submodules that live on the external git server.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce your issue, but I'd like to update my test for your reference:

1. Create a Git team project "git5" in TFS 2015, create a new solution "project2" and push it to TFS.
2. I use Visual Studio Team Services as the external git server. And create a Git team project "Git", as well as pushing a project "GitForVSO" in it.
3. Add the project "GitForVSO" to project "Project2" as submodule, the command is: `%Project2%>git submodule add https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Git/`
4. Commit the changes and push it to TFS. Now the the team project "git5" looks like the screenshot below:

[image]

5. Create an empty build definition and specify the "Repository" tab like the screenshot below:

[image]

- If I specify the "User name" and "Password" with TFVS alternate authentication credentials, which is also used to add submodule. Then I'll get a successful "Get sources".
- If I type the wrong "User name" or "Password", then I'll get a "401" error.

[image]

There is no error like "Too many redirects or authentication replays" under my test. You may check my steps to see whether there is something different from yours.

Comment: What do you get it you try to build the TFS 2015 got repo with submodules ticked. The build for dtmland is failing when building TFSGit with remote submilodules.

Comment: @MrHinsh Excellent and thorough response - I've since discovered there are at least two pieces to my problem. I've explained them both them in my question.